# I can't find 'org.smslib.gateway.modem.Modem' is SMSLib jar

Tags: java, sms, smslib

I want to follow [this example](https://github.com/smslib/smslib/blob/dev/smslib/src/test/java/org/smslib/Test_IPModem.java) of using [SMSLib](http://smslib.org/) to send an SMS to my mobile using a modem but I cannot find `org.smslib.gateway.modem.Modem` in the [SMSLib (Java - jar file) v3.5.4](http://smslib.org/download/) that I downloaded.

**Where can I download `SMSLib.jar` that has all the needed files?** Please help, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As this example in the `dev` branch referes to a class which exists in the `dev` branch. You could clone the repository and build a package from that branch.

```
git clone https://github.com/smslib/smslib.git
cd smslib/smslib
mvn package
```

After that you have the library available in `target/smslib-dev-SNAPSHOT.jar` which you can use for the example to run.

Or you clone the repository and open the maven project in the project root in your IDE. Then you could play with the code in `smslib/src/test/java/org/smslib/Test_IPModem.java`. A build in your IDE will do all the dependency related stuff for you.

**Down voting for a correct answer?** The class `o.s.g.m.Modem` does not exist in version `v.3.5.4`.

[image: unit test class Tes_IPModem]
[image: used class Modem]

This fact can easily be verified.

```
jar tf smslib-3.5.4.jar | grep "modem/Modem"
org/smslib/modem/ModemGateway$IPProtocols.class
org/smslib/modem/ModemGateway$ModemTypes.class
org/smslib/modem/ModemGateway.class
```

Whereas the class exist in the `dev` snapshot.

```
jar tf smslib-dev-20151220.150109-6.jar | grep "modem/Modem"
org/smslib/gateway/modem/Modem.class
org/smslib/gateway/modem/ModemResponse.class
```